# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not include in response when using a POST request

Tags: nginx, cors

I have the following in my nginx config:

```
location / {
    # CORS
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST' always;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/guacamole/;  # systemd: tomcat9
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /;
    access_log off;
}
```

When I send a `POST` request to the server, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not present in the response. It is, however, when I send a `GET` request. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that the proxy was overriding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. I fixed this by adding `always`:

```
    # CORS
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST' always;
```